# How can I display the numbers in a for loop from 1-entered value?

Tags: java

So I am working on this homework problem called "pennies for pay" and I am basically done except for one issue. My for loop prints out the number of the inputted number that many times if that makes sense?

```
public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //INITIAL VARIABLES
        int workdays;
        double money;
        double total = 0;
        double add;

        //GATHERING NUMBER OF DAYS WORKED
        System.out.println("For how many days will the pay double? ");
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        workdays = a.nextInt();


        //PARTIAL OUTPUT
        System.out.println("Day\t\tTotal Pay");
        System.out.println("__________________________");



        //FOR LOOP
        for(int payday = 1; payday <= workdays;payday++){
        money = Math.pow(2,payday - 1);
        System.out.println(workdays +"\t$\t"+ money/100);
        total = total + money/100;
        }


        //MORE OUTPUT
        System.out.println("__________________________");
        System.out.println("Total\t$\t" + total );
    }
}
```

When I input 12 for days, the number 12 repeats itself 12 times. how can I get it to go from 1-12 please and thank you.

Comment: run:
For how many days will the pay double? 
12
Day  Total Pay
__________________________
12 $ 0.01
12 $ 0.02
12 $ 0.04
12 $ 0.08
12 $ 0.16
12 $ 0.32
12 $ 0.64
12 $ 1.28
12 $ 2.56
12 $ 5.12
12 $ 10.24
12 $ 20.48
__________________________
Total $ 40.95
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Comment: Try printing `payday` in the loop instead of `workdays`

Comment: Could you include an explanation about what your code / assignment is supposed to be doing here?

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are printing the variable workdays in which it's value doesn't change inside the loop, that means it's constant.Since your target is to output pennies per day you should try this code if it helps

```
for(int payday = 1; payday <= workdays; payday++){
    money = Math.pow(2,payday - 1);
    System.out.println(payday + "\t$\t" + money/100);
    total += money/100;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add some explanation; explain why does this code work?

Answer (score 0):

The value of workdays variable is always 12 if you input 12. In your System.out.println inside the loop, use payday instead of workdays. Because payday is the one being incremented for each iteration.

That should fix it.